# How do I change the email displayed on the print version of my CV/resume?

Tags: support, developer-story, cv-export

I found every place I could to change my email and an old email address is still appearing on the print version of my CV. This old email doesn't work and it's generating awkward exchanges with potential employers. How do I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at your [Preferences Page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current) and see if you have different "Q&A Emails" and "Jobs Emails" addresses.

Your Jobs Email will be used if it exists (we're moving away from that because we're revamping our entire email sending infrastructure), otherwise your Q&A Email will be used, which is the preferred one going forward.

Make sure to click the Save button if you change/remove your Jobs Emails email.

[image: EMail Settings]

Comment: It was the job board email. Fixed now.

Comment: Now with the new email settings feature, these areas don't exists anymore. How can we change the email address displayed on the print version of the CV/resume using the new settings?

Comment: how do i do this today?